# How to store my GPG key passphrase by using Kleopatra?

Tags: gnupg

I generate the GPG key by following [Github doc instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/generating-a-new-gpg-key) and the doc remind me that I can store my GPG key passphrase by using Kleopatra to acheive that I don't need to enter the passphrase every time. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the following setting:

Kleopatra Settings > GnuPG System > GPG Agent > Expire cached PINs after N seconds

Set it to 0 to make the cached password forgotten immediately.

Source: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/185424